# $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is open for any set $A$ of points in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

**Theorem.** *The set of interior points of any set $A$, written $\operatorname{int}(A)$, is an open set.*

So I know for proving any set to be open, we take a arbitrary element in that set and want to choose a radius at which open sphere of that radius lies completely in that set.

Let $p\in \operatorname{int}(A)$, then by definition of int($A$), there exist an open sphere of $p$ with radius $r$,  $S_{r}(p)\subset A$.

But we want a radius $r_1$ around $p$, such that $S_{r_{1}}(p)\subset \operatorname{int}(A)$. Now **my doubt starts**.

Ok, we know that $\operatorname{int}(A)$ is always a subset of $A$, so we want to reduce the radius $r$ to $r_1$ , but for that , procedure the book chosen is beyond my understanding even we try to imagine it by making diagrams.

Please check the attached picture and if someone help me in understanding this, I shall be very thankful to him/her. [image]

Comment: It looks like a very bad book. The proof is meaningless. Why not simply prove that $S_{r/2}(y)\subset \text{int}(A)$ ? If $x\in S_{r/2}(y)$, then $S_{r/2}(x)\subset S_r(y)\subset A$, hence $x\in \text{int}(A)$.

Comment: Imagine it first in one dimension perhaps. If the number zero was contained in a one-dimensional ball of radius 3 ( the interval $(-3,3)$) and we were to consider an element in that ball, say the number 2. But the biggest radius that I can give the ball that contains 2 so that it is contained in $(-3,3)$ is the radius $1=3-2=3-d(0,2)$. Try drawing the picture for what I just illustrated.

Comment: I'm deeply intrigued, what book is this?

Comment: Also the word 'sphere' is disputable. The relevant term is 'ball'.

Comment: Thanks for answering fellows. The books is " Topology And Modern analysis " by George F. Simmons "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner approach is to show $S_r(x)$ is an open set for all $x \in X$ and $r>0$, as a lemma of sorts.

This is in fact what they're really doing from line 5 onwards, anyway.

To prove the lemma follow the book's proof. (So we have fixed but arbitrary $x \in X$ and $r>0$ from now on).

To see that $S_r(x)$ is open we need to show that every arbitrary point $y \in S_r(x)$ is an interior point of $S_r(x)$: so having such an arbitrary $y$ we note that by definition of $S_r(x)$ we have $d(x,y) < r$. Then define the "wiggle room" $r' = r-d(x,y) >0$. The claim is then that this $r'$ "witnesses" that $y$ is an interior point of $S_r(x)$ which means

$$S_{r'}(y) \subseteq S_r(x)\tag{1}$$

To prove $(1)$ we show the inclusion by picking any $z \in S_{r'}(y)$. Again we know $d(z,y) < r'$. We **need** that $z \in S_r(x)$ so we **want** to show $d(x,z) < r$ by definition.

Now we use the triangle inequality (via the only other point that we know anything about, our old friend $y$):

$$d(x,z) \le d(x,y) + d(y,z) < d(x,y) + r' = r$$

as $r'$ was defined as $r-d(x,y)$ from the start. So we have what we wanted: $d(x,z) < r$ and $z \in S_r(x)$ and $(1)$ holds.

As all points were arbitrary, $S_r(x)$ is open.

---

Now the proof about $\operatorname{int}(A)$ being open: it's the same procedure: to show a set is open we pick any $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$ and show it is an interior point of $\operatorname{int}(A)$. Knowing $x \in \operatorname{int}(A)$ tells us there is some $r>0$ such that $S_r(x) \subseteq A$. The claim is that in fact $$S_r(x) \subseteq \operatorname{int}(A)\tag{2}$$ and we are done: the same $r$ witnesses that $x$ is an interior point of $\operatorname{int}(A)$ as well. To see $(2)$ (an inclusion) we pick $y \in S_r(x)$ and show $y \in \operatorname{int}(A)$. We use the lemma above that $S_r(x)$ is open so $y$ is an interior point of it and so $r'>0$ exists so that $S_{r'}(y) \subseteq S_r(x)$. So $$y \in S_{r'}(y) \subseteq S_r(x) \subseteq A$$ and so $y \in \operatorname{int}(A)$ and $(2)$ has been shown. QED.

Comment: Thanks Henno Brandsma's for making this much simple for me

Comment: $S_{r'}(y) \subseteq S_r(x)$. So $$y \in S_{r'}(y) \subseteq S_r(x) \subseteq A$$ and so $y \in \operatorname{int}(A)$  ' This  is true na because we successfully find an open sphere around a arbitrary point $y$ of $S_r($x$)$ which contains in $A$ so all points of $S_r($x$)$ has open sphere contains in $A$ , so $x$ is also one of them that's why $x$ is in int($A$). Am i thinking right na ??

Comment: @user926846 We have $y$ in $\text{int}(A)$ because we have a ball $S_{r'}(y)$ around it that is a subset of $A$. This makes it by definition an interior point of $A$. As this holds for all $y$ we have shown the inclusion $S_r(x) \subseteq \text{int}(A)$ and that shows finally that $x$ (the *arbitrary* point of $\text{int}(A)$) is an interior point of $\text{int}(A)$ using the ball $S_r(x)$.

Comment: yeah thank you so ooo soooo much.

Answer (score 4):

The proof from the picture is wrong, because $z \in S_r(x)$ does not imply that $z \in \operatorname{Int} A$. It is also needlessly complicated. A correct proof is as follows:

Let $x \in \operatorname{Int} A$ so there is some $r > 0$ satisfying $S_r(x) \subseteq A$. It suffices to show that $S_r(x) \subseteq \operatorname{Int} A$. So take any $y \in S_r(x)$ and put $r_1 = r - d(x, y)$. Then $S_{r_1}(y) \subseteq S_r(x)$ since for $z \in S_{r_1}(y)$ we have that

$$d(z, x) \leqslant d(z, y) + d(y, x) < r_1 + d(y, x) = r.$$

It follows that $S_{r_1}(y) \subseteq S_r(x) \subseteq A$, so $y \in \operatorname{Int} A$ as desired. $\square$

---

Side note: denoting the sets $S_r(x)$ and calling them *spheres* is awkward, since the standard definition involves open **balls** which are usually denoted $B_r(x)$.

Comment: I think it is still needlessly complicated. You are proving more than the theorem's statement.

Comment: You could replace $S_r(x)$ with $S_{r/2}(x)$, then put $r_1 = r/2$ independently of $y$ and argue it is simpler (which I would not agree with), but I don't believe it's possible to simplify any more.

Comment: Thanks Adayah's

Comment: +1.....I prefer the notation $B(x,r)$...... $B_r(x)$  can be awkward when "$r$" is actually a complicated expression. Also, when discussing two metrics $d,e$ on the same set, you need a subscript or superscript $d$ or $e$ attached to the "$B$".